# How to calculate the average selling period from inventory list (uneven intervals)?

Tags: time-series, poisson-distribution, mean

Will I be able to calculate the average sales time (number of days) for an item, simply from the following 6 data points? Or will I need to repeatedly collect data, such that I for each day (say in the next 14 days) have the following data?

```
PUT UP FOR SALE WITHIN    NUMBER OF ITEMS
The last day                       17,319
The last 2 days                    30,832
The last 3 days                    44,328
The last 7 days                    96,829
The last 14 days                  177,765
Total                           1,272,306
```

Once an item is sold it no longer appears in the list above. And all items are removed after approximately 2 months.

The guess (of the top of my head) would be to estimate some sort of Sigmoid function, and then calculate the average sales time on that. But having only 6 observations -- and not knowing which initial parameters I should start with -- means that it doesn't converge to anything reasonable. I also remember learning something about the Possion distribution that related to time, but I've completely forgotten it.